# ORDER By clause with an expression

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have following query.

```
SELECT 
    mp.id 
FROM
    p_maint_prior pmp
    JOIN maint_prior mp ON(pmp.cid=mp.cid AND pmp.main_pr_id = mp.id)
WHERE
    pmp.property_id = 12345
    AND pmp.cid = 235
    AND pmp.remote_primary_key IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY 
    mp.maint_prio_type_id = 3,
    mp.maint_prio_type_id DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

With this query it gives me priority if it has type id 3 otherwise it will gives random. Would like to know more about expression used in ORDER BY clause.

Comment: Could you be more specific? What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close.  This `ORDER BY` puts 3 *last* not *first*:

```
ORDER BY mp.maint_prio_type_id = 3, mp.maint_prio_type_id DESC
```

The reason is simple:  "true" is bigger than "false".  This is simpler to understand if you do:

```
ORDER BY (mp.maint_prio_type_id = 3)::int, mp.maint_prio_type_id DESC
```

This gives "true" a value of "1" and false a value of "0".  The sort order is then obvious.

If you want "3" first, then put the DESC next to the first key:

```
ORDER BY (mp.maint_prio_type_id = 3) DESC, mp.maint_prio_type_id DESC
```

This is an odd construct, but -- as with many things in SQL -- one gets used to it pretty quickly.